# How to pass a function return value as an argument in R

Tags: r

It seems very much like a silly question: I don't get why I get the error in the below example. Shouldn't R evaluate rnorm() before its return value is passed to save() as an argument? Why does it work with an object, not a function?

```
> ls() 
character(0)
> save( rnorm(30), file="/tmp/RtmppMIFFg/data.RData")
Error in save(rnorm(30), file = "/tmp/RtmppMIFFg/data.RData") :    
object ‘rnorm(30)’ not found
> a <- rnorm( 30)
> save( a, file="/tmp/RtmppMIFFg/data.RData")
> class( rnorm(30) )
[1] "numeric"
> class( a)
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: The first argument of `save` (`...`) takes the names of objects to be saved. In order to save the result, you have to assign it a name.

Comment: The key line of code in `save` is `names <- as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]`, which means any value to pass to `...` gets converted to a character string eventually and the `get` like utilities are used to actually retrieve the objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is a clear "duh" moment: RTFM. Save takes not the objects themselves, only their names. [lmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4895725/lmo) basically provided the answer.